# How can i expose my nginx EKS cluster to the world?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform

I am trying to deploy this basic nginx image on an eks cluster but cannot seem to reach it when trying to hit the public IP.
I am using the official EKS module and have this setup:
[image]

I also have this deployment setup using the k8s provider:

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "helloworld" {
    metadata {
       name = "helloworld"
    }
    spec {
      replicas = 2
      selector {
        match_labels = {
          app = "helloworld"
        } 
      }
      template {
        metadata {
          labels = {
            app = "helloworld"
          }
        }
        spec {
          container {
            name = "nginx"
            image = "nginx"
            port {
              container_port = 80 
            }
          } 
        }  
      } 
    }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "helloworld"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = "helloworld"
    }
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = 8080
      target_port = 80
    }

    type = "NodePort"
  }
}
```

When i go to check `kubectl describe pods` i am told that the service is unreachable:

[image]

what am i missing here?

Comment: share describe pod screenshot or details instead of writing in own words.

Comment: @HarshManvar i've added an update screenshot

Comment: how you are trying to access the service ? so using terraform pod getting deployed but facing issue after that is it so ? did you tried <Node IP>:<Node port>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to reach it when trying to hit the public IP

Expose your nginx with a load balancer service:

`kubectl expose deployment helloworld --port 80 --target-port 80 --name helloworld-service --type LoadBalancer`

Get the external IP:

`kubectl get services helloworld-service`

Do a `curl <external IP>` and your helloworld nginx should response to you.

Comment: thanks for that! these service types confusing the hell out of me lol